# my jython procedure coudn't detect errors of my shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jython, oracle-data-integrator

I succeed to create a script which slipt file and I succeed to call this script by a jython procedure,

This is my Jython proc :

```
import os    

cmd = "<%=odiRef.getSchemaName("script_path","D")%>/split_ncl.sh <%=snpRef.getSchemaName("data_in","D")%>/<%=odiRef.getOption("REP_FILE")%> <%=snpRef.getOption("FILENAME")%>"  

retcode = os.system(cmd)  
if retcode > 1 :      
    raise "Fatal ListError (%d)" % retcode, "Erreur de split"
```

And this is my script shell split_ncl.sh :

```
exec > Log/errors.log                                                                      
exec 2>&1

data_in=$1
fichier=$2

cd $data_in

#Purge des fichiers 

rm -f Split/INIT_ENC.dat
rm -f Split/INIT_ELP.dat


grep -P "^..........ENC" fichier ><!> Split/INIT_ENC.dat
grep -P "^..........ELP" $fichier >> Split/INIT_ELP.dat
```

All is working good. I add `exec > Log/errors.log` and `exec 2>&1` for redirect all errors of my script into errors.log

when I execute the script  in UNIX environnement it's working well it could log errors but when I use ODI and call this script by Jython procedure like what I did, it can't detect error of my shell script , for example if I put `fichier` instead of `$fichier` (missing $), it's not correct And it couldn't detect the error.  How can I resolve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You should use subprocess library of Python instead of os.

`os.system()` sends the command, and returns success message. Let's say it is asynchronous, it does not wait for process to finish. It only triggers the process.

`subprocess.call()` sends the command, waits for process to complete then returns the return code of process.

So if you change your code to :

```
retcode = subprocess.call(cmd) 
if retcode > 1 :     
raise "Fatal ListError (%d)" % retcode, "Erreur de split"
```

And also one more thing, if you try to catch errors, change your condition statement to `retcode != 0` since erroneous processes can return anything other than 0.

More info : https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system